# Position fixed element at bottom of parent div with same parent width

Tags: html, css

How can I position a textarea at the bottom of the parent div and also make the textarea the same width?

The problem I have now is that the textarea expands all the way to the right side of the page.

Html

```css
html,
body {
  height: 90%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="middle">
    <p>
      Textarea should be placed at bottom of the 'blue' div, with the same width
    </p>
    <textarea class="bottom" placeholder="Textarea..."></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a simple example of the problem that I have: https://jsfiddle.net/hu45v46p/1/

How can this be solved with html and css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `position: fixed`, you want to give it `position: absolute`.

By default, it will be slightly larger than the blue box (because of the borders). You can accommodate for this with `width: calc(100% - 6px)`:

```css
html,body {
  height: 90%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="middle">
    <p>
      Textarea should be placed at bottom of the 'blue' div, with the same width
    </p>
    <textarea class="bottom" placeholder="Textarea..."></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code below.

```css
html,body {
  height: 90%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.blue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="blue">
    <p>Textarea should be placed at bottom of the 'blue' div, with the same width</p>
      <textarea class="bottom" placeholder="Textarea..."></textarea>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed the *value* of the `position` *property* to `absolute`for the `.bottom` *div* and added some basic *CSS* browser reset `* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}` which fits the `textarea` nicely inside the `.middle` *div*:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

html, body {
  height: 90%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="middle">
    <p>
      Textarea should be placed at bottom of the 'blue' div, with the same width
    </p>
    <textarea class="bottom" placeholder="Textarea..."></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed;` is relative to your *viewport* which is why you're getting those results for the textarea.

```css
html,body {
  height: 90%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.bottom {
  /*fixed to absolute*/
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="middle">
    <p>
      Textarea should be placed at bottom of the 'blue' div, with the same width
    </p>
    <textarea class="bottom" placeholder="Textarea..."></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```